# Какими способами можно решить капчу на mail.ru

Tags: python, captcha

У меня есть скрипт, который автоматически вводит все данные для создания аккаунта, но на последнем этапе есть капча, которую нужно как-то решить, платные способы не подойдут( тк я бомj

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй Capmonster, XEvil, там есть тестовые периоды